# domain of square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What is the domain and range of square $\sqrt{3-t} - \sqrt{2+t}$? I consider the domain the two separate domain of each square root.
My domain is $[-2,3]$. Is it right? Are there methods on how to figure out the domain and range in this kind of problem?

Comment: To find the domain, start with all real numbers and throw away any number that causes an error in either radical. If you can't evaluate one of the radicals, you certainly can't evaluate their difference. (The solution you found is correct, by the way.)

Comment: @AustinMohr Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the domain. As to the range, use the fact that as $t$ travels from $-2$ to $3$, $\sqrt{3-t}$ is decreasing, and $\sqrt{2+t}$ is increasing, so the difference is decreasing.

Comment: You are welcome. As to "how to," I caanot do better than the answer by Austin Mohr, regrettably deleted. Start with all the reals, and throw away the bad ones.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I converted my partial answer to a comment after noticing that eLg wanted a discussion of both domain and range.

Comment: I should add that throwing away the bad ones can be extremely difficult. For example, if we have $f(x)$ in the denominator of our expression, we need to determine the $x$ at which $f(x)=0$, in general a highly non-trivial task. Similar considerations apply to $\ln(f(x))$ (we have to determine where $f(x)\le 0$) or $\arcsin(f(x))$ (we have to find where $|f(x)|\gt 1$).